# Umbraco does not call controller action

Tags: umbraco

The problem is: after entering my web application in the browser at / en-US / About does it does not call the controller action. Controller:

```
public class AboutController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController
{
    // GET: About
    public ActionResult About(RenderModel model)
    {
        return View("About", model);
    }


}
```

This happens after adding Home in the Culture and Hostname domain "http: // localhost: 54315".

And after entering en-Us / Home normally enter the action Controller:

```
 public class HomeController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController
    {
        // GET: Home
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Home(RenderModel model)


        {

            var lang = LanguageHelper.GetLang(Request);
            var home = new Home(model.Content, model.CurrentCulture);
            home.Topic = "aloha";
            //Do some stuff here, then return the base method
            return View("Home", home);
        }


    }
```